# how do i fix "Array.prototype.map() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function"

Tags: javascript, arrays

website works fine, but in terminal i have this warning `Array.prototype.map() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function` . How do i fix this?

i tried using forEach, there is no warning but the section doesn't show what I wrote.

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5mOO.png)

Comment: `filter` the data first, and then `map` over the array that returns.

Comment: Welcome to SO btw. Note: code that you have worked on to solve the problem be included in your question as a [mcve], and not as an image. You can use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the question edit toolbar to help you. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0):

You have to listen to the error. It's because you're not returning anything if the value's category is not "education". You must have a return value for every element in the array for `map` to work. As @Andy pointed out in the comments, you  have to `filter` the array for the category you want, and *then* `map` the items to the values you want.

Answer (score 0):

As Andy said, to make sure everything runs smoothly, I recommend using a `.filter` function first, then the `.map` function. To give you a better idea, here's an example:

```
    Data
      .filter(val => val.category === "education")
      .map((val, id) => return (<Card key={id} ...>));
```

If no Data meet the filter criteria, the function will return an empty array. This array will then be passed to `.map`, resulting in no actions being taken. Put simply, if there are no matches, there is nothing to display.